# How do I send ALT+F1 through ALT+F7 via ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, special-characters

I'm using the (Open)ssh client in Konsole, and I cannot figure out how to send ALT-Fx keys, so I can switch between terminals on the remote machine. I need it so I can switch the GUI on/off via `init 3` and `init 5`, because the remote machine is really underpowered. I have been looking all over, finding answers for putty, weird ssh clients, macs, phones...but not just bog-standard OpenSSH in Konsole. Can anyone at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Keys you send via SSH go to the remote side as bytes (or sequences of bytes) as if you piped the bytes to your local `ssh`. On the remote side they optionally go through a tty, finally to whatever program you run there. I don't think any of these layers can affect virtual terminals. There is `chvt` (see `man 1 chvt`) and you need access to some `/dev/ttyN` to use it, so e.g. `sudo sh -c 'chvt 4 >/dev/tty2'` should work even in an SSH session; but I'm not sure this is the right thing for what you ultimately want to do.

Answer (score 1):

When you interact with a Linux machine locally, you in reality interact with a terminal emulator (client) that is connected to a "Linux OS" (server). Your particular client happens to have 7 connections to the server. When you "switch beеtween terminal with ALT-Fx keys" you switch your client between those 7 connections. I will emphasize, this switching happens on the client (terminal emulator), the server knows nothing about which exact connection is active on the client. It only processes input from each of the 7 connections.

When you use Konsole to connect via ssh you use another terminal emulator (Konsole) to make a new connection (8th if those 7 were the only ones) to a remote server over ssh. Your Konsole after this has only one connection to the remote server.

So "sending ALT+F1 through ALT+F7 via ssh" is meaningless for switching between your single connection; and I would imagine a practical joke of switching the connections of a bloke who is currently connected to the same Linux server locally is not what you want.

Switching local terminal from GUI (ALT+F1) to non GUI (ALT+F7) won't affect remote server performance, all 7 terminal connections exist regardless of you looking at them. Even unplugging the monitor from the wall won't help.

GUI is too costly to run and you don't need it - kill the Xserver and clients.

#### For those reading this because of question heading

##### You probably want to multitask on a remote server.

For that you can fire up another Konsole and connect over ssh to the same server again (establishing another connection)

##### Best practice is to use a terminal multiplexer

A program that runs on the remote server and makes connections to local machine on your behalf. Old school is `screen`, new and hype - `tmux`. Both are good.

When using a multiplexer you make a single connection to the server over ssh, start a multiplexer if it doesn't already run and it creates local terminal connection on your behalf. If you need another one - press a hotkey and it creates another local terminal connection. You can move this connections between virtual windows, split said windows vertically, horizontally. copy and paste from one pane to another.

A killer feature is that if your ssh connection is broken for some reason, your terminal multiplexer session continues to run on the remote host. For example if you connect over ssh and run a `cp` command for some huge files, broken connection means copy fails, if you run the same command in a multiplexer it just continues running. You can connect to the server again, connect to a running multiplexer session and all your windows and panes will be just where you left them.